# Доступ к закрытому атрибуту класса

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты

Здравствуйте. Нужно Создать класс телевизор. У пользователя должна быть вводить номер канала, а также уменьшать/увеличить громкость канала. Программа должна следить за тем чтобы уровень громкости оставался в пределах нормы.

```
class Tv:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Телевизор включился!')
        self.volume = 15

    def first(self):
        print('Первый канал предствляет...')

    def tnt(self):
        print('Тнт представляет...')

    __act = True

    def volume(self, val=0):
        if Tv.__act:
            self.volume += val
        else:
            self.volume -= val
        Tv.__test()
        Tv.__act = True

    def __test(self):
        if self.volume <= 0:
            print('Уровень громкости слишком низкий, увеличьте его!')
            self.volume = 0
        elif self.volume >= 100:
            print('Уровень громкости слишком высокий, уменьшите его!')
            self.volume = 99
        else:
            print('Уровень громкости нормальный')


def main():
    tv = Tv()
    choice = None
    while choice != '0':
        print("""
        Телевизор включен [......__]
        --------------------------
        0 - выключить телевизор
        1 - включить первый канал
        15 - включить 'ТнТ'
        --------------------------
        '+' - увеличить громкость
        '-' - уменьшить громкость
        """)
        choice = input('Ваш выбор: ')
        if choice == '1':
            tv.first()
        elif choice == '15':
            tv.tnt()
        elif choice == '+':
            val = input('Увеличить громкость на: ')
            tv.volume()
        elif choice == '-':
            val = input('Уменьшить громкость на: ')
            tv.volume()
        else:
            print('Такой кнопки нет')
```

Проблема: Когда пользователь вводит '-' т.е уменьшает громкость, надо изменить закрытый атрибут класса с True на False. Конечно, можно сделать атрибут класса открытым, но цель - произвести данную манипуляцию через закрытый атрибут класса. Желательно показать способ через свойство @property

Comment: Зачем закрытый атрибут именно класса, а не экземпляра класса?

Comment: Для себя, я только учусь ООП и все возможные манипуляции, идут только на пользу. Именно поэтому я попросил привести пример с использование свойства @property

Comment: заголовок *«Доступ к закрытому атрибуту класса»* не имеет отношения к фактическому вопросу: «как через property изменить частный атрибут» (`@volume.setter`)